# Implement "Navigate To Definition" (Ctrl+Click) in Visual Studio extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, go-to-definition

I am writing a Visual Studio extension and I want to implement the Ctrl + Click command for my own file type. This is similar to the C#/C++ editor whereby Ctrl + clicking on a type name will take user to the definition of that type (aka. Go To Definition command.)

Is there any sample on how to achieve this? I searched on Microsoft Docs website but I couldn't find anything that I want.

Comment: Forgot to say that I also want to make the text under cursor become a hyperlink when user presses Ctrl and mouse over the text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ctrl+Click Go To Definition example from VS Productivity Power Tools may get you started.

Description https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.CtrlClickGoToDefinition

Source code https://github.com/microsoft/VS-PPT/tree/master/src/GoToDef

Comment: Thanks. That's very helpful. I read the source code and I understand that it invokes the built-in GoToDef command to handle the actual opening of the target file. For my extension, it's not a programming language, so I can't invoke the GoToDef command. I have to open the file manually, using VsShellUtility.OpenDocument() function. Do you know how I can navigate to a particular line number within the target file?

Comment: @superkinhluan EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = dte.ActiveDocument.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection; ts.MoveToLineAndOffset(…);